# How to serialize each item in IEnumerable for ajax post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a PartialView that displays `IEnumerable<Movie>`.

**_MoviePartial.cshtml**

```
@foreach(var movie in Model) {
    <div class="content">
        <span class="image"><img src="@movie.Posters.Profile" alt="@movie.Title"/></span>
        <span class="title">@movie.Title</span>
        <div class="score`">
            <span class="critics-score">@movie.Ratings.CriticsScore</span>
            <span class="audience-score">@movie.Ratings.AudienceScore</span>
        </div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Add Movie", "Add", "MyMovies")
    </div>
}
```

When the user clicks the "Add Movie" ActionLink I am going to do an ajax post to add the selected movie to the users collection. My problem is that I would like to send the entire selected `Movie` class to the "Add" action but not sure how to serialize each movie since the entire `Movie` class is not rendered in the PartialView, just a few properties. I know I can serialize something like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(movie));
</script>
```

But I'm not sure how that would work inside a foreach loop that renders html, especially inside a `PartialView`.

So, just to be clear, when a user clicks the "Add Movie" `ActionLink` I would like to send the serialized `Movie` class for that respective movie to my controller via ajax.

My questions is...

Is there a better way to serialize each movie and append it to it's respective anchor? I know there's the `data-` html5 attribute but I thought they only allow string values, not json objects. I also know I could use jQuery's `.data()` function but I'm struggling to think through how to get that to run from a PartialView, especially since the html rendered by `_MoviePartial.cshtml` may be returned from a controller via ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A framework such as [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) would really make your life easier here.

Basically, you would:

1. Load all the movie data as a JSON array using eg: `Json.Encode(Model);`
2. Create a [foreach template](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html) using knockout to render your data. Knockout will then handle the trouble of keeping the displayed movies to a complete movie model.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to return a JSON object as the response with two properties; HtmlString and Data.  HtmlString may contain a rendered partial view and Data may contain a serialized object of the request.

I find this is insanely easier to work with JSON, then trying to return HTML with embedded JSON object(s).